# Vim: make text go red or screen flash after 80 column mark?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Is there a way to make Vim warn me after a line has exceeded `n` characters?

Something simple like a screen flash or the text go bold red or something.

**!!** Bonus points if `n` can be made a variable that is easy to set in each individual window (I use 80 columns usually, but 100 columns for PHP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. If your version of Vim is at least 7.3, just set `'colorcolumn'` option (see [`:help 'colorcolumn'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27colorcolumn%27)), e.g. to 81:

   ```
   set colorcolumn=81
   ```

   It can also highlight more than one column:

   ```
   let &colorcolumn = join(range(81, 400), ',')
   ```
2. If you have Vim version prior to 7.3, you may want to define custom highlighting rule to highlight all characters after specific column, e.g.:

   ```
   syn match tooLong /\%81c.*$/
   hi link tooLong Error
   ```

To have different settings for different file types, put this commands into appropriate filetype plugin (for example to `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim`). Or define autocommands (see [`:help :autocmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd)) triggered by `FileType` event (see [`:help FileType`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileType)) in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: or if you want to shorten it :set cc=80

Comment: `colorcolumn` doesn't add only one column: `set colorcolumn=81,82,83` or `let &colorcolumn=join(range(81,999),",")`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, thank you for the correction, I somehow missed this back then. Updated the answer to fix this, weird wording, formatting and provide hyperlinks to the documentation. By the way, `999` is too much, Vim won't highlight more than `256` columns.